# Get self defined AfterProperties column in Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

i want to show an error message, whenever the user adds an item.
So i use code similar to that:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
 properties.Cancel = true;
 properties.ErroMessage = properties.AfterProperties[columnname];
}
```

Unfortunately it only work, when the columname ist an default column.
For self defined columns it doesn't work.
I get this error message:

```
event receiver has canceled the request
```

I tried everything:
The columnname is right, the column is not null,..
If i write a console application getting this columns, everything will work well.
Only in the event receiver it doesn't work.

Can anybody help? Would be great!

Answer (score 0):

hopefully not too stupid a question but are you using a column name that SharePoint recognizes? The reason I ask is that you mention that these are self defined columns. When you define a column via the UI, the column name behind the scenes ends up as something similar but not the same.

This [page](http://blogs.syrinx.com/blogs/sharepoint/archive/2008/02/06/best-practices-for-working-with-column-names-in-sharepoint.aspx) gives you a bit of an over view of DisplayName vs InternalName.  And as the author mentions, things get even more complicated when you rename a column via the UI.

Comment: So i checked your page but i think that's not the problem.
I have worked with self-defined columns for a while and i have never had any problems.
thanks for your answer. Do you know anything more?
When i write a console application getting the columns, everything works well.
Only in the event receiver it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you attach your debugger to the ItemAdding event? can you inspect the column properties there?